# How to call a field through a lookup for the same object

Tags: apex

I have a vfp that brings the contact data of an opportunity. I'm going to call it contact X, and for that I do a select on the object "OpportunityContactRole" and use a lookup field to get data from the contact X "contact.".

But I also need to reach the fields of another contact, and I'm going to call contact Y. For that I created a new lookup field, but how can I make the call?

I still get confused a lot in the relationship of objects...

Controller:

```
public List <OpportunityContactRole> getAvalist(){ 
         if(avalista==null){
             avalista=[SELECT Id,contactId, contact.Name,contact.CPF__c,contact.MailingCity,contact.MailingStreet,contact.MailingState,
                       contact.MailingPostalCode, contact.Procurador_do_Contato__c.CPF__c//this is my last try..I thought of something like contact.Procurador_do_Contato__c.contact.CPF__c...
                       FROM OpportunityContactRole 
                       WHERE OpportunityId =: idOpp
                      ];
         }
```

Comment: What is "a vfp"?... A [Visual FoxPro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_FoxPro) database?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's a pretty common abbreviation for "VisualForce Page"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a custom relationship field, and want to query/access data on the related (parent) record, the `__c` at the end of the relationship field needs to change to `__r`

So instead of what you have

```
[SELECT Id, contactId, contact.Name, contact.CPF__c, contact.MailingCity, contact.MailingStreet, 
    contact.MailingState, contact.MailingPostalCode, contact.Procurador_do_Contato__c.CPF__c
FROM OpportunityContactRole
...
]
```

you'd use `Procurador_do_Contato__r` instead

```
[SELECT Id, contactId, contact.Name, contact.CPF__c, contact.MailingCity, contact.MailingStreet, 
    contact.MailingState, contact.MailingPostalCode, contact.Procurador_do_Contato__r.CPF__c
FROM OpportunityContactRole
...
]
```

In a way, this is also similar to what we do with standard relationship fields. E.g. `ContactId` changes to `Contact` (the 'Id' part is dropped) when we want to access related data.

Accessing it in Apex follows the same pattern.

```
System.debug(myOppContactRole.Contact.CPF__c);
System.debug(myOppContactRole.Procurador_do_Contato__r.CPF__c);
```

Comment: The mnemonic that I've used in the past works in English, but I'm not sure how helpful it'd be to others, so I left it out of the main answer. That mnemonic is "I'm not looking for a **\_\_c**ustom field, I want **\_\_r**elated data"

Comment: wow, thanks for the help and explanations! @Derek F